# Automating user interaction from within Session 0

Tags: windows, winforms, session, ui-automation

I am running on Windows Server 2012. I have a service that creates several processes, one of them is a GUI client. The process in high level is as follows:

1. Service runs a launcher exe
2. The launcher exe launches an AutoIT compiled exe
3. The AutoIT compiled exe launches a winform exe

The winform exe does two things:
a. It write a file to the disk on program startup (test.log)
b. It waits for a keyboard press "c" to write a second file to the disk (test2.log)

The AutoIT script does two things:
a. It launches the said winform exe
b. It sleeps for 5 seconds and then send "c" (Send command)

If I start running this chain manually (from step 2) - everything works fine and 2 files are being created. I guess this happens because I have an interactive session (specifically 2) so it's a no brainer here. However, if I run it from the service, everything runs in session 0 (I verified this with ProcessExplorer) but only the first file is being written. Meaning, the keystroke message was not read by the winform exe.

I read about Session 0 isolation which means that user input from other sessions can't interact with programs (services) running in session 0. However, all of the processes mentioned now run in the same session 0. So I'm not sure why my application doesn't get the keyboard strokes? Any workaround for this? Please note that running under a different session is probably not possible, as the server must run without user logged on and as far as I know, you can't launch a session yourself without logging into the system.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your service probably runs under Local System or Local Service account (it's always "logged in" in some sense). But you can change this behavior to allow the service running under any specified account with access to the desktop.

1. Go to menu "Start->Computer->Manage".
2. In the "Computer Management" window select "Services and Applications->Services".
3. Find your service and call "Properties" by popup menu.
4. Open "Log on" tab.

You have 2 options here:

a. Choose "Local System account" radio button and check "Allo&w service to interact with desktop".
b. Choose "This account" and type or "Browse..." the account you need.

Option (b) could make sense if you set up an auto logon on the machine (in this case you may run as Administrator and have an access to the desktop simultaneously).

Option (a) is applicable only if you don't need running as Administrator. Hope it helps.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Vasily, I actually tried both options but it still gets created in Session 0, only under a different user. Still doesn't work :(

Comment: With option (b) probably you need to set up an auto logon. Maybe I misunderstood your message `the server must run without user logged on and as far as I know`. Is it some policy set on the server? If yes, it's impossible to have an access to any GUI.

Comment: Auto logon set up is described here: http://serverfault.com/questions/269832/windows-server-2008-automatic-user-logon-on-power-on

Comment: Of course, you need to restart the service after applying settings. Just in case. It may require adding user account to the Administrators group.

Comment: After my experiments I could not find a way to interact with the desktop from a service. My colleagues from another project say the same: it's most probably impossible.

Comment: But we run Jenkins slave as not a service in a VNC session (using TightVNC). And it works under Jenkins ecosystem. Probably video card drivers should be updated to set up screen resolution properly.

Comment: The check list for Jenkins can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123530/pywinauto-can-it-be-made-cross-platform).