# pywinauto can it be made cross platform

Tags: automation, pywinauto

My `Python` application has  windows is client and server as `Linux`. My aim is to automate windows `GUI` application with `pywinauto` from `Linux` server.

Can `pywinauto` be made cross platform?

Comment: What do you mean saying "`from Linux server`"? Do you want running automation script on Linux while GUI actions take place on Windows?

Comment: The question is unclear. Please add more details so that we could help you. Currently I'm voting to close the question. And yes, pywinauto is going to be cross-platform in mid-term future, but Windows client should be tested from Windows. Remote running of the automation script is another topic. The Python script itself must run on Windows and it should be called from Linux remotely.

Comment: The answer is probably here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171331/how-to-execute-windows-commands-remotely-from-linux-machine-using-rdesktop-comma

Comment: Thank you for your reply and link you shared.you are correct I want to run  my automation script on Linux while GUI actions takes place on Windows (Something similar to Selenium / Sikuli execution).

Comment: OK, I've tried to explain possible steps in the answer. So the task is very broad. Some specific sub-problems can be solved in different ways. Maybe you will need to ask separate questions on some of them (or find existing answers - it's better).

Comment: Raj, is the answer below correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using pywinauto immediately. But you may copy pywinauto script to the target Windows machine and run it remotely using Jenkins, for example. Or any other CI server. Master node can be on Linux. So Windows node can run as a slave. But there are several requirements for the Windows slave (this check list is based on my recent experience).

- Windows slave can [be set up with auto logon](https://superuser.com/questions/460475/windows-7-auto-logon).
- VNC server software (TightVNC or UltraVNC, for example) should be installed.
- Video card drivers should be up-to-date for better screen resolution (and for black screen prevention).
- Jenkins slave process must run as not a service (i.e. in the existing desktop, so Jenkins task would have an access to the GUI). Just do NOT click menu "Run as a service" in JNLP agent window.
- Do not use Remote Desktop connection from another Windows machines (reboot may be required to restore GUI session with VNC client/server pair).
- Of course, Python+pywinauto must be installed on Windows node. Just in case.
- If UAC is enabled on Windows node, in some cases it should be disabled (if you have to deal with admin access like GUI installers do).

On Linux you need to set up the VNC client and Jenkins. For other CI servers steps may be similar but with some differences.